# How to upload file using socket.io-stream?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, stream, socket.io

This is my source code.

```
<server.js>

var app = require('./app.js');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = app.listen(53322, function() {
    console.log('server is working at port 53322');
});

var io = socketIO.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
        console.log(data);
        var filename = path.basename(data.name);
        var filepath = path.join('./uploads', filename);
        var ws = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
        stream.pipe(ws);
    });

});



<client script>

window.onload = function () {

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:53322');

    $('#media-form').submit( function(e) {
        var file = e.target[0].files[0];
        var filename = file.name;
        var filesize = file.size;
        var enc = e.target.encoding;
        var stream = ss.createStream();

        ss(socket).emit('file', stream, {
            data : file,
            size : filesize,
            name : filename,
            enc : enc}
        );

        var blobstream = ss.createBlobReadStream(filename);
        blobstream.pipe(stream);

        return false;
    });

};
```

I inserted `console.log(data);` in the server code to check whether the file is uploaded properly. For example, I select 'IMG_4433.jpg' image file in the input element and click submit. After 'file' event done, my console print this message.

```
{ data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 0f fe 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 0b 01 0f 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 92 01 10 00 02 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 98 01 12 00 03 ... >,

size: 393825,

name: 'IMG_4433.JPG',

enc: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

I found that the 'IMG_4433.jpg' is uploaded into 'uploads' folder. But it's file size is 0 byte. I think that maybe the problem is in the data Buffer... but I don't know how to handle it.

Help!

Comment: Did you solve this ? I am at the same place now. I am now trying to use socket-file-upload plugin though.

Comment: I also get this `TypeError: inpt is null` error in the browser console when I use `uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("siofu_input"));` code in the client. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler, I would suggest using something like Dropzone.js
It does all the painful work for you and is pretty to use!

Comment: Ah.. sorry but my html page interface is just needed input type='file' form... And I want to know the basic stream usage first, for I'm new to node js... ^^;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package `socketio-file-upload`
it will handle everything for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30995127)